# Two different file references in bash for loops simultaneously

Tags: bash, loops

Is there a way to use two different file references in for loops simultaneously? Something like:

```
for file in file1 file2 file3; for name in name1 name2 name3
do
  awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};($1 in a)' ${file}.txt ${name}.txt > ${name}_extract.txt
done
```

I tried also with a nested for loop that didn't work:

```
for file in file1 file2 file3
do
  for name in name1 name2 name3
  do
    awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};($1 in a)' ${file}.txt ${name}.txt > ${name}_extract.txt
  done
done
```

What I would like to achieve is to extract lines from 'file1.txt' and 'name1.txt' that match by their first column. Vice versa for file2.txt/name2.txt and file3.txt/name3.txt.

Comment: Two `for` loops requires __two__ `do` statements.  You are missing one.

Comment: In the future, when you have a shell script error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Comment: @John1024 Yes, I missed one `do` statement, although it still doesn't work, see edit. It produces no error but all but one output file is empty.

Comment: Are you trying to loop over all combinations of variables (e.g. "file1" & "name1", then "file1" & "name2", then "file1" & "name3", then "file2" & "name1", etc) or just over corresponding items (i.e. just "file1" & "name1", then "file2" & "name2", then "file3" & "name3")? Two loops will get you all combos; if you want just corresponding items, you need a single loop (and probably to have the items in arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, it's not clear if you want to run 3 iterations or 9.  Assuming you want only 3 iterations, I like the format:

```
while read file name; do 
  ...
done << EOF
file1 name1
file2 name2
file3 name3
EOF
```

Comment: Great, thank you @William Pursell, it works beautifully!

Answer (score 2):

If the files and names are really called `file1`, `file2`, `file3` and `name1`, `name2` and `name3`, then you can do something like this:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    printf '%s\n' "file: file$i, name: name$i"
done
```

You replace the `printf` statement with whatever you need – the important part is how you access the files and names.

If they have arbitrary names, though, you have to do something like prepare two arrays and then loop over indices:

```
files=(file1 file2 file3)
names=(name1 name2 name3)
for (( i = 0; i < ${#files[@]}; ++i )); do
    printf '%s\n' "file: ${files[i]}, name: ${names[i]}"
done
```